# js/jquery/other library plugin to convert HTML->XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

Do you know of any JS library that converts HTML->XML?

And not only clean HTML, but also malformed (or 'dirty') real world HTML?

Is such a library available in JS or do I have to go in for a server side library (like in Java etc)?

Comment: html is xml, do you have a particular specification you have to validate against?

Comment: @Sinetheta, *XHTML* is XML.  HTML is not XML.

Comment: change the doctype to xhtml and then you have a xml file.

Comment: Does the resulting XML need to be valid?

Comment: Yes it does need to be valid...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several forgiving HTML parsing JS libraries targeted to Node, but should work in the browser if you really need that.

- [htmlparser](https://github.com/tautologistics/node-htmlparser)
- [htmlparser2](https://github.com/fb55/node-htmlparser)
- [HTML5 Parser](https://github.com/aredridel/html5)

You could combine one of those with [something](https://github.com/soldair/node-jsontoxml) that outputs XML from JS objects.