# html to xml conversion using javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, json, html

Is it possible to convert all div child information into XML or JSON using JavaScript?

```
$("#droppable").droppable({
drop : function(event, ui) {
    var id = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
    var cloneObj = $((ui.draggable).clone());
    $(cloneObj).removeClass("draggable ui-draggable");
    if (id === "txt") {
        inputOBj = document.createElement("input");
        inputOBj.setAttribute("id", "txt" + i);
        $("#droppable").append(inputOBj);
    } else if (id == "combo") {
        inputOBj = document.createElement("select");
        inputOBj.setAttribute("id", "select" + i);
        console.log("");
    }
  });
```

Comment: From what I understand html and xml are closely related. Any specific reason you would want to convert to one from the other?

Comment: thanks for reply.

I want to generate html code using Drag -n-Drop in javascrip.

I able to create the hmtl form in DnD but to save into seperate file 
i require xml/json or any which can be usefull to save the generated code into seperate file.

Comment: This answer might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866997/js-jquery-other-library-plugin-to-convert-html-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is property called outerHTML.
It Sets or retrieves the object and its content in HTML.
U can  use it in following way.
e.g:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#p').click(function() {
        alert($('#p')[0].outerHTML);
    }); 
});
```

tip: p is your any tag ID in body of page.

Comment: Good  Answer... it also work. but what is difference between above 2 answer?

Answer (score 9):

I believe you can use XMLSerializer to do this.

```
var yourString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(cloneObj[0]);
```