# Output valid xml with jquery.html()

Tags: jquery, html, xml

I want to export some html as valid XML.

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/617391/

```
<div id="test">
  <p data-test="&nbsp">
  Foo&nbsp;bar
  </p>
</div>
```

The output of `$('#test').html()` is: `<p data-test="&nbsp;"> Foo&nbsp;bar </p>`. This is valid html. But the entity `&nbsp;` is not valid in XML. So a valid XML output would be `<p data-test="&nbsp;"> Foo&#x00A0;bar </p>`.

How can I create numerical entities/valid XML with `$(...).html()` ?

Comment: Given that all `html()` is intended to do is to be a wrapper around getting the `innerHTML` of an element..... you wouldn't?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML

Comment: This really is an example of an https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem .  Rather than asking how to make `html()` return valid xml, you should instead ask *how to make valid xml*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get XML use XMLSerializer

```
var s = new XMLSerializer();
var d = document;
var str = s.serializeToString(d);
console.log(str)
```

This will return the current document to valid XML.

Working example [here](https://jsbin.com/qunotujatu/edit?html,js,console,output).

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer) for more info on XMLSerializer.

Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14021633/5549391) answer.